# Issues trying to create a test average calculator in C# and utilizing the bootstrap modal window

Tags: c#, asp.net, calculator, bootstrap-modal

Here is my problem.  I'm using Visual Studio 2015 webform.  I've created a test average calculator.  All the code works but when I place this in a modal, clicking the calculate button within the modal closes the modal.  The calculation works but I need to click on the modal window to see the results.  Here is the aspx code

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication7._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testAvgModal">Test Average</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="testAvgModal">

                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Test Average</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <br />
                    <section class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                 <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="t1TextBox">Test 1:  </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input class="form-control" runat="server" id="t1TextBox"  required="required"  type="text" placeholder="77"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <section class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                 <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="t2TextBox">Test 2:  </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input class="form-control" runat="server" id="t2TextBox"  required="required"  type="text" placeholder="77"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <section class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                 <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="t3TextBox">Test 3:  </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input class="form-control" runat="server" id="t3TextBox"  type="text" placeholder="77"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <section class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="avgOutputLabel">Average Test Score:  </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" runat="server" id="avgOutputLabel"> </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>

                           <div class="row">
                                <section class="form-horizontal">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="calculateButton_Click" >Calculate Average</button>
                                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" >Clear</button>
                                            <%--<asp:Button ID="calculateButton" CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" OnClick="calculateButton_Click" Text="Calculate Average" />--%>
                                            <%--<asp:Button ID="clearButton" CssClass="btn btn-warning" runat="server" OnClick="clearButton_Click" Text="Clear" />--%>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </section>
                           </div>

            </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info">Close</a>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Here is the code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebApplication7
{
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            double test1;
            double test2;
            double test3;
            double average;

            test1 = double.Parse(t1TextBox.Value);
            test2 = double.Parse(t2TextBox.Value);
            test3 = double.Parse(t3TextBox.Value);

            average = (test1 + test2 + test3) / 3.0;

            avgOutputLabel.InnerText = average.ToString("N2");

    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your modal is not closing, it's not being shown.

You must understand the difference between *server-side* code and *client-side* code.

When you create a modal with bootstrap it is executed in the client-side via javascript, whenever your page is re-rendered it disappears as the page returns to it's initial state.

Your buttons inside the modal have a "submit" action, it means the data will be posted to the server and the server will return the full page with new content.

So, when you press the calculate button, the data is sent to the server, the page is re-rendered and it does not have the modal open as the user never clicked on the button.

The right way to achieve what you want is through ajax, do an async call to some resource in the server which does the calculation and in the response of the ajax call update the text box with the new values.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  My modal does show and will close.  The results of the calculation do not show unless I close the modal and open it back up.

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie.  How do I the ajax portion?

Comment: For the first part, I think you did not understood how it works, it's shown once, then the page is POSTed back and when it's re-rendered it's not re-opened, that's what I meant with "not shown". For the ajax part... well, you have a bit of work ahead if you did never before an ajax call, this can help you understand how to do it: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx